# Accessing mongoose query result

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**Query**

```
 Blog.find({date: 'December 27, 2014'}, function (err, data) {

        console.log("Data: " + data);
        console.log("Value: " + data.coverFilename);
 }
```

**Dump**

```
Data: { _id: 549de8f6afa8b87c2139559d,
  tags: 'tag1, tag2, tag3 hallo',
  permaLink: 'testtitle',
  coverFilename: '3b6f0110-8d53-11e4-9ef3-9503045c44e0.jpg',
  content: 'test',
  date: 'December 27, 2014',
  timestamp: '1419634934689',
  title: 'testtitle',
  __v: 0 }

Value: undefined
```

`coverFilename` obviously exists, so why is it **undefined** if I try to access it? I don't have a clue

Comment: does data returns an object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `find`, `data` is an array of matching objects, not just one.  Use `findOne` instead of you only expect a single result.

```
Blog.findOne({date: 'December 27, 2014'}, function (err, data) {
    console.log("Data: " + data);
    console.log("Value: " + data.coverFilename);
}
```